# How to Insert collection in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I have a collection and want to Insert in Acumatica with the help of Rest API endpoint, please let me know is there any way

I want to expose a endpoint and try to insert a collection in Acumatica by third party ,is there any way to do it.

Comment: If it is just data like in an excel  spread sheet, have you checked Import Scenarios?

Comment: Yes there is. Have you checked out training course I330? examples posted here: https://github.com/Acumatica/Help-and-Training-Examples/tree/2023R1/IntegrationDevelopment/I330